# SQL / ORACLE Missing keyword

Tags: sql, oracle, syntax, ora-00905

I am working on an sql file trying to make a script which brings back either all the data from the tables shown or all the data from the tables plus 3 months back of data. I keep getting an error that says  `error 00905 missing keyword` and I don't understand why.

I looked at the syntax and it all looks right to me. I will put a marker at the point it says the error occurred(at the first inner join). I changed all the table names to make it look better since it's over the syntax.

Any help would be great thank you. This is only a section of the code but I'm sure it has to be in here.

```
WHEN Table_typ_cde = '1' -- Pulling all data --
  THEN
    INNER JOIN  Table   acp ON Table_oid = Table_oid
    INNER JOIN  Table   loss ON Table_oid = Table_oid
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Table veh ON Table_oid = Table_oid and Table_nbr=1
    INNER JOIN Table   brnch ON Table_OID = Table_oid
    INNER JOIN Table   a ON Table_OID = Table_oid
    INNER JOIN Table   c Table_OID = Table_oid
    INNER JOIN Table   s ON Table_OID = Table_oid
    INNER JOIN Table   r ON Table_OID = Table_oid
    INNER JOIN Table   grp ON Table_oid = Table_oid
    INNER JOIN Table on Table_id = Table_id
    WHERE Table_ID <> 2
 WHEN Table_cde = '2' -- Pulling all data within the last 3 months along with all present data --
 THEN
    INNER JOIN  Table   acp ON Table_oid = Table_oid
    INNER JOIN  Table   loss ON Table_oid = Table_oid
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Table veh ON Table_oid = Table_oid and Table_nbr=1
    INNER JOIN Table   brnch ON Table_OID = Table_oid
    INNER JOIN Table   a ON Table_OID = Table_oid
    INNER JOIN Table   c ON Table_OID = Table_oid
    INNER JOIN Table   s ON Table_OID = Table_oid
    INNER JOIN Table   r ON Table_OID = Table_oid
    INNER JOIN Table   grp ON Table_oid = Table_oid
    INNER JOIN Table on Table_id = Table_id
    WHERE Table_ID <> 2
    AND df.DATE_CREATED BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -6)
    AND sysdate
END                                         
) core
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot break the `JOIN` using `CASE`. i've seen this in some part of your query,

```
THEN
   INNER JOIN  Table   acp ON Table_oid = Table_oid
   INNER JOIN  Table   loss ON Table_oid = Table_oid
```

that is wrong, you must supply the tablename before `INNER JOIN` keyword.

Comment: so are you saying since i have started with and inner join then and AND command i cant have a CASE statement inside that?

Comment: If i understand your question, then yes. The simple syntax of join is `SELECT * FROM tableA INNER JOIN tableB on tableA.col = tableB.col` you can add `case after `ON` but not on or before `JOIN`

Comment: I'm sorry if im getting confused but isnt my CASE statement after the ON,'ON Table_ID = Table_ID'? I want to run the first statement, where it is getting the error, and then either take the first case or the second case. I need an if statement to choose which one to pick to add to the first statement and dont see any other way to do that.

Comment: can you post the whole query? thanks :D so we can locate where the real error is

Answer (score 0):

You have two sets of joins which appear to be equal.  Then you have a date filter which you wish to apply conditionally.  You need to apply that in the WHERE clause not the FROM.  Some like this

```
FROM  ... INNER JOIN  Table   acp ON Table_oid = Table_oid
    INNER JOIN  Table   loss ON Table_oid = Table_oid
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Table veh ON Table_oid = Table_oid and Table_nbr=1
    INNER JOIN Table   brnch ON Table_OID = Table_oid
    INNER JOIN Table   a ON Table_OID = Table_oid
    INNER JOIN Table   c ON Table_OID = Table_oid
    INNER JOIN Table   s ON Table_OID = Table_oid
    INNER JOIN Table   r ON Table_OID = Table_oid
    INNER JOIN Table   grp ON Table_oid = Table_oid
    INNER JOIN Table on Table_id = Table_id
WHERE Table_ID <> 2
    AND (Table_cde = '1' 
          or ( Table_cde = '2' 
          and df.DATE_CREATED BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -6) AND sysdate ))
```